# Google Cloud Functions - custom build step

Tags: typescript, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

In Google AppEngine there's the possibility to define a custom build step in the package.json file via `"gcp-build": "somethingsomething"`.
This step gets automatically executed after the installation of package dependencies.

I'm wondering if there's something similar for Cloud Functions?
I'm writing my functions in Typescript and I want to compile them on deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible, for now, on function. If you want to customize your environment, you can have a look to [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/). It's very similar to Function, but

- You have to package it in a container, that allow you to customize your execution environment
- You have to define a simple webserver which route the traffic to your "function endpoint" (many example in several language in the documentation)
- You can set the concurrency param to 1 if you want to have the exact same behavior as function, I mean a isolated execution per instance (only 1 request is processed in the same time on 1 instance).
- You can't answer to event yet. Only HTTP request is allowed with Cloud Run.

I [wrote an article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-and-cloud-function-what-i-use-and-why-12bb5d3798e1) on what I choose, when and why, and [another one on the lowest cost](https://medium.com/google-cloud/cloud-run-vs-cloud-functions-whats-the-lowest-cost-728d59345a2e)

Answer (score 1):

`gcp-build` works on the node.js 8 runtime, but not the node.js 10 runtime. I hope it will come to 10 eventually